Multi-threading causing an issue in Spring scheduler logging
I am using Spring scheduler and have a requirement to print the log inside the Spring scheduler after every minute. Below is the code & configuration for the Spring scheduler.
@Slf4j
@EnableScheduling
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventConsumer {

    private AtomicReference<LocalDateTime> lastLoggedTime = new AtomicReference<>(LocalDateTime.now());;

    public LocalDateTime getLastLoggedTime() {
        return lastLoggedTime.get();
    }

    public void setLastLoggedTime(LocalDateTime lastLoggedTime) {
        if(lastLoggedTime.isAfter(this.lastLoggedTime.get())) {
            this.lastLoggedTime.set(lastLoggedTime);
        }
        else{
            log.info("Time trying to update is in past EventConsumer");
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 5, fixedDelayString = "30000")
    public void pollAxonMessages() {

        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        if (isLogginEnabled(getLastLoggedTime(),60,currentTime,"Event Consumer")) {
            log.info("Started polling ");
            setLastLoggedTime(currentTime);
        }
    }

     public boolean isLogginEnabled(LocalDateTime lastLoggedInTime,
                                   Integer loggingInterval,
                                   LocalDateTime currentDateTime,
                                   String consumerName){
        log.info("LocalDateTime : {} , loggingInterval : {} , currentDateTime :{} consumerName: {}", lastLoggedInTime, loggingInterval, currentDateTime, consumerName);
        return lastLoggedInTime.plusSeconds(loggingInterval).isBefore(currentDateTime);
    }

}

YAML file configuration for spring scheduler.
spring:
  task:
    scheduling:
      pool:
        size: 8

I am using Spring Boot version 2.4.1 and deploying the application in PCF Cloud Foundry. The issue is that I can see scheduling-2 & scheduling-4 threads running inside the event consumer and when one of the threads (scheduling-2) is updating the lastLoggedTime, the other one is still not receiving the update and using the old lastLoggedTime value causing the same statement to print twice with in 60 seconds rather than once.
Can you please let me know what did I missed in the above code causing this issue?

Its not clear what logging you mean - add more info. However if calls to setLastLoggedTime is multi-threaded there is an obvious race condition as you've used if (get()) { set(); } when other update/compare calls would be appropriate.
